# Acesso por ip Phpmyadmin

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, wamp

Dentro da pasta c:\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf existe a linha abaixo para liberar o acesso do phpmyadmin para todas maquinas na rede:

```
  <IfDefine APACHE24>
   Require all granted
```

Gostaria de saber se tem como mudar para liberar somente por ip, pois tenho receio de deixar aberto dessa forma. Tentei assim mas deu erro e o apache não subiu:

```
  <IfDefine APACHE24>
   Require local, 192.168.200.71
```

Obrigado

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adicione estas linhas ao arquivo "phpmyadmin.conf":

```
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from All
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from SeuIpAqui
```

Pode adicionar quantos "Allow from" você quiser.

Fontes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631269/how-to-secure-phpmyadmin
        http://mixeduperic.com/ubuntu/how-to-restrict-phpmyadmin-ip-address.html

Comment: Exatamente isso, muito obrigado!